# is there any way to get display refresh rate programmatically?

Tags: android

As the title, i want to get the refresh rate of android phone then show to user. Is there any way?

Updated: what is refresh rate?  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate

Comment: Doesn't [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRefreshRate()) work?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The solution is:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
float refreshRating = display.getRefreshRate();
```

Thanks to THelper.