# Screen refresh rates on Android

Tags: android

So I've been tinkering with the Android kernel and want to change the screen refresh rate. I looked into the hardware related file like hardware and DisplayHardware but they don't seem to have anything related to it. There is an api for getting the current refresh rate but that doesn't help much. Where can I find the code related to the screen refresh rates and  is that something that can be changed on Android?

Edit: I dug deeper and there is a setVsyncRate that can be used to control how often the screen is drawn by dropping some screen updates. It might not be same as changing the refresh rate but it's something I can work with for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: [Seems related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379708/is-there-any-way-to-get-display-refresh-rate-programmatically)